# Hyperlink function in formula field results in HL_ENCODED text

Tags: url, hyperlink

I want to create hyperlink text on Long Text Area field.While creating a flow I used following link in formula field.
hyperlink("https://.my.salesforce.com/a021100000GblsrAAB/a0311000007oFjp",{!RelatedAcc.Name})
and updating a long text area field on Account object
It displays the link in following text format.
**_HL_ENCODED_https%3A%2F%2.com_HL_Test+Case_HL__blank_HL_.**

Instead of link it displays _HL_ENCODED_ and _HL__blank_HL_ . Is there any way out to display the link on long text area field on multiple text link using flow. For example [Test Case1](https://google.com), [Test Case2](https://google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Variable in flow and insert "https://.my.salesforce.com/a021100000GblsrAAB/a0311000007oFjp" as variable value.

After that while updating field use Variable name instead of direct link.

Comment: I created a variable txtlink and added link in default value. Also , added in formula field like
Hyperlink(txtlink,”Test Case”). This formula field is going to update Long Text 
Area Field. Still ,displaying same _HL_ENCODED_

Comment: Change Long Text area to Rich Text Area 

Text Area (Rich) Allows users to enter formatted text, add images and links. Up to 131,072 characters on separate lines.